# Move mesh to exact location with extra precision

Tags: mesh

I want to move the selected mesh forward 5 units along x,y,z axis (x+5, y+5, z+5). 
I used the "transform" settings in the properties, but it does not allow me to move mesh with enough precision.

When the current value for "x" is 0.000005 and I move it to 5.000005, the value becomes 5.000000 instead of 5.000005.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3168/599