# Restricting vertices to a 3D grid

Tags: modeling, snapping

I'm trying to prototype models of spaceships that could be built in a voxel based game(think Space Engineers).  While this is fairly easy to do manually it would be much quicker if I could make all vertices snap to a 3D grid while extruding, scaling, etc.  I know you can do this for individual actions, but is there a global setting?  More precisely I want to ensure that the coordinates of any vertices are integer values.

Comment: Also related :  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/75842/29586

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you perhaps talking about the [Snap to Grid](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Tutorials/Modeling/Meshes/Snap_to_Mesh) tools?

You simply click to the magnet icon to enable that, pick your poison in terms of what you want to snap by (side-note: doing so by volume is *fantastic* when setting up rigs). Works in object/edit modes, and with all sorts of translation/scaling/rotating.

Edit: If you want to modify the increment size, try [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/48244/19302).

[image: simple-poor-gif-record]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yikes, I forgot to capture my cursor. Hopefully it all still makes sense.

Comment: Perfect!  And thanks for the quick answer :)