# Why does the median z value seem wrong?

Tags: vertices, axis, interface

I have a circle. I checked every single vertex's z value individually, and they're all 0.0:

[image]

But when I select all the vertices, the median for the z value is not 0:

[image]

Why isn't it showing as zero? This has been very frustrating for me. I kept trying to set the value on a larger mesh to 0 (using s -> z -> 0) to no avail. But it didn't work. So I cut down the mesh to just this small portion and I saw this problem still.

Here's the file in case you're interested:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jqi3eljppr8gcvv/uneven.blend?dl=0

This brings up a side issue I've been having using blender. I do an action (like s -> z -> 0) and it brings up a little window in the bottom left:
[image]
Is it still waiting for my input? What's it doing there? I can make it go away by deselecting vertices or something. Sometimes, like when I do a bevel, its purpose is obvious, and I change values in there and it affects the geometry. But most of the time it sits there and I need to do something funky to make it go away.

Thanks for any help with either problem!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3168/digits-of-precision-of-vertices-coordinates

Comment: Hm -- using @Henning's blend file, I get exact float `0.0` if I execute this in a Blender scripting window:
`>>> np.median([(bpy.context.object.matrix_world @ v.co).z for v in bpy.context.object.data.vertices])`
and yet I also see `-0.000458 mm` as the displayed value. I think this may be related to the way Blender modifies the Transform median to reflect Scene Units; if I switch Length to "Adaptive", I get `-0 m`, without any small non-zero part. Setting `Unit System` to `None` gives `0.000061`, though, which surprises me a bit.

Answer (score 1):

**The side issue** can be gotten rid of by clicking anywhere on your screen. It's a part of Blender.

It's used to set how you want your scaling, moving, rotating, added object, etc.

Example: You added in a UV sphere but you don't want many vertices so you change the sphere using it.

Answer (score 0):

There might be another vertex hidden on the underside of your object.